# How do attach objects to a moving mesh seq to all the frames?

Tags: mesh, tracking, obj

[image: Frame1]
I am working with a mesh sequence imported into Blender using the stop motion OBJ plugin. I'm encountering an issue where I can successfully join an object to the first frame of the mesh sequence, but it disappears on any subsequent frame. How can I attach a particle emitter or object to all frames of the mesh sequence, ensuring that it moves along with the mesh?

Subsequent frames it just disappears
[image: FramesX]